# How to make DataFrame column of equal length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, padding

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
            data     top  number
497     Grossmont      5       1
498       College      5       2
500     Education     99       3
503          2004     99       3
504       Granite     227      3
```

The aim is to pad the top column and concatenate with the number column in such a way that the length  of top column should be of the same length.

The output should look like this:

```
            data     top  number
497    Grossmont    10005       1
498      College    20005       2
500    Education    30099       3
503         2004    30099       3
504      Granite    30227       3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html), but first convert `int` values to `str` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) if necessary:

```
df.top = df.number.astype(str) + df.top.astype(str).str.zfill(4)
print (df)
          data    top  number
497  Grossmont  10005       1
498    College  20005       2
500  Education  30099       3
503       2004  30099       3
504    Granite  30227       3
```

Last if necessary convert to `int`:

```
df.top = (df.number.astype(str) + df.top.astype(str).str.zfill(4)).astype(int)
print (df)
          data    top  number
497  Grossmont  10005       1
498    College  20005       2
500  Education  30099       3
503       2004  30099       3
504    Granite  30227       3
```